# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_e07..42c14904, O_RDWR)

Tags: php, session, warnings

I got this error when I changed my index.php file into index.html file and then changed back again to its original index.php file

Can anyone tell me what to do to prevent this error?

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_e0725de9954b..2c14904, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/accn/public_html/dbc.php on line 42
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/accn/public_html/dbc.php:42) in /home/acceptin/public_html/dbc.php on line 42

Comment: Please post your code. This description is essentially useless without it. :-(

Comment: Is /tmp full? Use the `df /tmp` command to find out.

Comment: The answer's in the error: permission denied. You need your webserver to be allowed to write to `/tmp` if that's where you're storing sessions.

Comment: do you have anything like html tag above your `session_start();`, remove it if there is.

Comment: @Sjoerd where can I find /tmp ? Im new to this thing, I'm beginner for programming

Comment: @KalpeshMehta I dont have any HTML at the top of my session_start()

Answer (score 19):

Create folder "tmp" on your root directory with permission 777 then before start_session,

```
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');
```

Done

Comment: for me it worked when I put this folder inside www, not root folder.

Comment: Simply creating the folder with permission 777 was enough in my case (actually permission 700 worked). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I was facing the same problem and your solution just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

when using ini_set be sure to set the path '/tmp' rather than just 'tmp' didn't work in my case 'tmp'. just like

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp')
```

Steps to solution

1. create folder tmp inside of the website root
2. change permission to 777

   sudo chmod -R 777 tmp
3. enter this line above session_start() in your code

   ini_set('session.save_path', '/tmp');

done.