# Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/\sess_j62ge3scjn69ep2lrpmm7oelf6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in

Tags: php, api, yahoo, yahoo-api

I tried using login yahoo sosial PHP, using from GitHub : [Yos-Social-Php5](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5)

I set `OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,OAUTH_DOMAIN,OAUTH_APP_ID`

and result :

**Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/\sess_j62ge3scjn69ep2lrpmm7oelf6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo-php5\examples\common.inc.php on line 55**

What I try :

1. Set folder tmp in root folder(htdocs/tmp) with permission 777. (Same) [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779889/warning-session-start-function-session-start-open-tmp-sess-e07-42c14904?answertab=active#tab-top)
2. Using another GitHub ([bigodines](https://github.com/bigodines/yos-social-php5)). (More error) [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983825/yahoo-social-sdk-php-setup-help)

Code :

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files'); // line 53
session_save_path('/tmp/');               // line 54
session_start();                          // line 55
```

Any advice?

Comment: Backslash before the *s* ? `/tmp/\sess_`

Comment: very simple: sampe code run on Linux system, because it have tmp folder, you run on Windows, so you change `session_save_path` to other path

Comment: path on windows have to be "C:\xamp\tmp" or "tmp", not '/' on first of path

Comment: looks like it's work (no more error just blank, it's so weird should be show sample code) with `ini_set('session.save_path', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp');`

Comment: you can try and run with: `session_save_path('tmp/');` I think so

Comment: @PhuDuy i did, but error like i post, where i should be put the folder tmp? in folder yahoo?/root?lib(yahoo)? because the sample is blank

Comment: what result when run `ini_set('session.save_path', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp');` or session_save_path(C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp)

Comment: @PhuDuy blank, might be because i put folder tmp in root, but when i change to folder yahoo `c:\xampp\htdocs\yahoo-php5\tmp` result is same