# WordPress error after hard disk went full and site crashed

Tags: php, wordpress

The hard disk of our web server went full overnight and one of our sites crashed. We increased disk space and now at the top of admin backend, we are seeing this error:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_9mrmtgmqb49bfs661n4pqhagq1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/prikkabelled/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-simply-order-export/classes/class-export-import-tool.php on line 140
```

Many other plugins are acting weird as well. What do we need to do?

Here is a possible solution: [Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_e07..42c14904, O_RDWR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779889/warning-session-start-function-session-start-open-tmp-sess-e07-42c14904)

But not sure what they mean by, "then before start_session,".

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your server it's looking for the session info of your session cookie. But that's only a warning not a big problem. The problem it's that warning it's breaking your headers because you're showing errors in the HTML. In a production site that should be deactivated.

Check the `wp-config.php` of your WordPress and set this on that file:

```
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Comment: This seems to have taken away the error messages. Now when I try to make a test xml export, I get this error: Test failed: FTP error: fopen(/tmp/test.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: That error says that file it's not on your server. The /tmp folder it's a temp folder so that file should be created by other process which has not been executed before the text xml export. That could be a problem of permissions on /tmp (very rare IMHO) or a problem in the filesystem due to the 0 bytes left on it. You should do a fsck on the filesystem to check it against file system problems.