# i have this code and it is working well on local host, but when i change the config.php to include server credentials i get this error;

Tags: php, session

Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_98399992455991a73aa6f9aa99dc6319, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/wwwfurahacentre/meru.furahacentre.org/index.php on line 2

Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: ) in /home/wwwfurahacentre/meru.furahacentre.org/index.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wwwfurahacentre/meru.furahacentre.org/index.php:2) in /home/wwwfurahacentre/meru.furahacentre.org/helpers/Functions.php on line 160

here is my code

Comment: I think there is `No such file or directory`. Is that path correct?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Code is probably not needed, the message indicates an environmental issue.

Comment: It look's like 2 errors one is read/write error or permission, the second is the header error looks like an output is send before header location load. some code would be good,

Comment: Sounds like either `/tmp` doesn't exist, or the web user cannot write to it (does not have write or execute privs)

Comment: @BlockchainOffice The Headers already sent are due to the first two errors being printed. Fix the session permissions issue, fix the Headers issue.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779889/warning-session-start-function-session-start-open-tmp-sess-e07-42c14904